# About Galois extensions and roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have a few questions about the next problem.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i /n})$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $a^n\in K$. Define $L:=K(a)$.

i) Show that $L/K$ is Galois.

ii) Show that $Gal(L/K)$ is cyclic.

iii) Show that $|Gal(L/K)|$ $|n$.

I think that $K$ is the extension of some root of unity over $\mathbb{Q}$. If $L=K(a)$, am I able to find explicitly $L$?

And for (i), it's enough to say that $a$ is a root of $x^n-1$ and show that is separable, then $L/K$ is Galois.

For (ii) and (iii), if I find $Gal(L/K)$ should be easy I think. The problem is that I don't see what is $Gal(L/K)$

I'm super confused, thanks in advance for any orentation.

Comment: For (i) you have to show that the extension is separable, which is easy since you're only dealing with characteristic $0$ fields, and that the extension is normal. For (ii), notice that if $\sigma$ fixes $K$, then it is entirely determined by where it sends $a$. But $a^n\in K$, and so $\sigma(a)^n \in K$. For (iii), since it's cyclic, you only have to use the generator whose existence you proved in (ii)

Comment: You are given that $a^n=b$ for some unknown $b\in K$. For i) you need to show that all the zeros of $p(x):=x^n-b$ are in $L$. Then that $L$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$ over $K$. Observe that $p(x)$ is not necessarily irreducible over $K$. For ii) you need to proceed as Max said - iii) is a by-product.